# How can you change Django loop body using javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, django

i was wondering if there is a way i can change the body of for loop in django using javascript each time i press a button.

in my case i want to display matches this week and when i press next i want to change the list using javascript and then pass it django template in the regroup part, i want to change the matches list.

i know how to write the code to make the new list and the previous and next buttons using javascript but i don't know how to pass it to django template

or maybe another way could be to write django code in javascript, anyone can help with either way?

---

in views.py , matches return a list of dictionaries from today to 6 days later

```
def home(request):
    start = datetime.now().date()
    end = today + timedelta(6)

    matches = request_games(today, after_week)

    return render(request, "sporty/home.html",{
        "matches": matches,
        "start" : start,
        "end": end
    })
```

---

in home.html

```
{% extends "sporty/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}


{% block body %}
<div class="box">
    {{start}},{{end}}
    
    {% regroup matches by date as date_list %}

    {% for date in date_list %}

        <div class="the_date">
            {{date.grouper}}
        </div>

        {% for match in date.list %}
            <div class="match_container">
                <div class="status">
                    {% if match.status_code == 1%}
                        {{match.minute}}'
                    {% elif match.status_code == 11%}
                        HT
                    {% elif match.status_code == 3 %}
                        Finished
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="match">
                    <div class="home">
                        {{match.home_name}} <img src="{{match.home_logo}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="score">
                        {% if match.status_code == 0 %}
                            {{match.time}}

                        {% elif match.status_code == 17 %}
                            TBD

                        {% elif match.status_code == 1%}
                            {{match.home_score}} : {{match.away_score}}

                        {% elif match.staus_code == 11%}
                            {{match.home_score}} : {{match.away_score}}

                        {% elif match.status_code == 3 %}
                            {{match.home_score}} : {{match.away_score}}

                        {% endif %}
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="away">
                        <img src="{{match.away_logo}}"> 
                        {{match.away_name}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

---

```
def request_games(start, end):

params = (
   ("season_id","1511"),
   ("date_from",start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
   ("date_to",end.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
);

headers = {
"apikey": //my api key
}

response = requests.get('https://app.sportdataapi.com/api/v1/soccer/matches', headers=headers, params=params)
r = response.json()

data = r["data"]
number = len(data)
matches = []
for i in range(number):
    match = {}
    match['status'] = data[i]["status"]
    match['status_code'] = data[i]["status_code"]
    match['minute'] = data[i]['minute']

    full_date = data[i]["match_start"]
    dt = datetime.strptime(full_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    match['date'] = dt.date()
    match['time'] = dt.time()
    match['start'] = full_date

    home_team = data[i]["home_team"]
    match['home_name'] = home_team['name']
    match['home_logo'] = home_team['logo']

    away_team = data[i]["away_team"]
    match['away_name'] = away_team['name']
    match['away_logo'] = away_team['logo']

    stats = data[i]['stats']
    match['home_score'] = stats['home_score']
    match['away_score'] = stats['away_score']
    matches.append(match)

matches.sort(key = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['start'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

return matches
```

Comment: It requires a bit more information. Like, what does the match model have as variables? Also, what do you mean by next? This looks like it puts up a week worth of matches. Do you want it to show next week's matches or just the next match after this week?

Comment: @BoobyTrap i edited the question and added the function, its not a model its an api request.

Comment: 1) If you are fine with loading a new page a form or an anchor with get parameters should be enough. 2) If you want to stay on the same page you need to make an ajax request. A response once sent to the user has no relation with Django you cannot change it.

Comment: @BoobyTrap i mean by next that i want to make 2 buttons, previous and next to show next and previous week's matches

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat the problem is i don't want to reload the page, so do you think there's a way to do it

Comment: @omaramgadd As I said in my comment you need to use ajax if you don't want to reload the page.

Comment: Okay, then another question, when a person reloads the page, do you want it to display the original week or the one that they stopped pressing previous or next on?

Comment: So essentially you have JSON data posted from Django's view into your HTML template, and you want to sift thru this data in JS? Id suggest to simply load all the data as JSON (like everything you want the user to see) then when you click next to load a second page, just access another part of the JSON data return and stored in JS. Example: arr[0] is page one, arr[1] is page two etc.. this way you don't have too always execute a URL to access some data

Comment: @BoobyTrap i think the original week if they refresh for simplicity

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat how can i make an ajax request and put the data in django template?

Comment: @jasonmzx i was planning to do a method in JS to make a request and bring list of matches form day x to day y then pass to django's template, but the problem is i don't want to write the html in javascript because i used the regroup and 2 other loops in django template and i can't do it again in javascript, so i just want to pass the requested list from js to django if this is possible

Comment: or i can do it all in javascript but im not sure how to write django's loops and regroup and html in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first, once you decide to start working on pages that do not refresh but still query the server and change, one of your solutions is to start using AJAX calls to query the server for different data.

This would add a bit of code to your project.
For example, your `home.html` template will need to be split into two. Make sure to also add jQuery to your head.

`sporty/home.html`

```
{% extends "sporty/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}


{% block body %}
    <div id="matchweek" class="box">
        {% include "sporty/matchweek.html" %}
    </div>
    <button type="button" value="p" onclick="weekControl(this)">Previous</button>
    <button type="button" value="n" onclick="weekControl(this)">Next</button>
    {% comment %} 
        Either place weekupdate.js in /static/ or give the path within static, 
        best would be to have a folder for javascript in static and use 'js/weekupdate.js' 
    {% endcomment %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/weekupdate.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

and `sporty/matchweek.html`

```
{{start}},{{end}}

{% regroup matches by date as date_list %}

{% for date in date_list %}

    <div class="the_date">
        {{date.grouper}}
    </div>

    {% for match in date.list %}
        <div class="match_container">
            <div class="status">
                {% if match.status_code == 1%}
                    {{match.minute}}'
                {% elif match.status_code == 11%}
                    HT
                {% elif match.status_code == 3 %}
                    Finished
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="match">
                <div class="home">
                    {{match.home_name}} <img src="{{match.home_logo}}">
                </div>
                <div class="score">
                    {% if match.status_code == 0 %}
                        {{match.time}}

                    {% elif match.status_code == 17 %}
                        TBD

                    {% elif match.status_code == 1%}
                        {{match.home_score}} : {{match.away_score}}

                    {% elif match.staus_code == 11%}
                        {{match.home_score}} : {{match.away_score}}

                    {% elif match.status_code == 3 %}
                        {{match.home_score}} : {{match.away_score}}

                    {% endif %}
                    
                </div>
                <div class="away">
                    <img src="{{match.away_logo}}"> 
                    {{match.away_name}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Because you will need to update the entire content of `matchweek` div every time.

`views.py`

```
def home(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        template = 'matchweek.html'
        direction = request.GET.get('dir')
        if direction == 'n':
            request.session['weekoffset'] += 1
        elif direction == 'p':
            request.session['weekoffset'] -= 1
    else:
        template = 'home.html'
        request.session['weekoffset'] = 0
    offset = request.session['weekoffset']
    start = datetime.now().date() + timedelta(days=7*offset)
    end = start + timedelta(days=6)

    matches = request_games(start, end)

    return render(request, f"sporty/{template}",{
        "matches": matches,
        "start": start,
        "end": end
    })
```

What you see in the function is a check if the request is coming from the AJAX call or not and determination on what to do from there.

`/static/js/weekupdate.js`

```
function weekControl(id) {
    var value = id.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: '', // The url suffix that leads to your home function, example: '/home/'
        type: "GET", // Http method
        data: {'dir': value}, // The data to be sent to the server.
        success: function (htmlres) { // What to do on success and response reaching back
            $("#matchweek").html(htmlres);
        }
    });
}
```

What you see here is the AJAX get call to your django view with the data of 'dir' and its value. When it is returned, jQuery will change the content of the `matchweek` div with the new content.

I haven't tested this but let me know if this works and if you have any questions.

Comment: Great answer, although I would say that you should have let the OP do some research on ajax and come up with the answer themselves.

Comment: thank you so much for your time and effort, yes it works but i had to move the buttons to match week.html because they disappear after one click, also the start and end date are not working as expected but i think i can fix it, im not familiar with ajax but i will spend some time learning it and if i have any questions ill ask you, thank you again!

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yeah, it is a good but I find that learning with an example and a starting point is often easier.

Comment: @omaramgadd Yeah, I looked at the start and end now and I shouldn't have added offset to the end, should have remained as 6 days -  `end = start + timedelta(days=6)`. The reason for it being that start is already with an offset, and end just adds 6 days to it.

Comment: @BoobyTrap hey again, i have a question in the success part, does the function always take the returned data from the view as an argument by default? i mean the 'htmlres' in the ajax code

Comment: @omaramgadd There are multiple options for the success parameters, when you specify one variable it is either an HTML body or JSON content (depends on what the view responds with and on a dataType parameter if specified). Ajax success also has other versions which can contain up to 3 parameters, you can read about them [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) if you scroll down to _success_. You can actually see there all the other options Ajax has as well.